# Accessing an arbitrary action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am somewhat confused as to how to properly access an action in a rails controller that is NOT associated with one particular model. The routing file, by default, seems to be routing the action name to "id". So if I type, say, /user/login, I end up with an error that says: "Couldn't find User with 'id'= login"

What is the proper way to access arbitrary action names in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a route for it, obviously. The request goes this way:

- first it hits a route
- from there it hits a controllers' action
- [an action may invoke a model] (optional, but common)
- controller specified a view and fetches data to render
- view is sent back in response to a request

`resource` and `resources` might not be obvious about what they do. But in fact, they are shorthands to corresponding collections of routes used quite often, like [this is what `resources` adds](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). And they're not monoliths, they can be customised to fit your needs. Providing options is just a start, you can provide a block to define your custom action routes for this resource like so:

```
resources :users do
  get :login
end
```

This will add a `/users/login` route that maps to `UsersController#login`, following Rails' conventions.

[See this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more details and don't forget to run `rake routes` to see what you have at the moment.